# How to parse date string to DateObject with a particular DateFormat

Tags: date-and-time

Very simple problem. This date as example: `"2/1/20"`. The date is the first of February of 2020.

How do I convert it to a `DateObject`? I tried the following code but I get a warning and oddly a "day" as the day.

```
In[57]:= DateObject["2/1/20", DateFormat -> {"Month", "/", "day", "/", "Year"}]
During evaluation of In[57]:= DateObject::ambig: Warning: the interpretation of the string 2/1/20 as a date is ambiguous.
Out[57]= DateObject[{2020, 2, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", 0., {"Month", "/", "day", "/", "Year"}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateObject[{"2/1/20", {"Month", "Day", "YearShort"}}]
```

> [image]

#### [`Docs >> DateObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html):

[image]